# Jenkins: custom command for any finished build from history with access to this build`s ID, ideally from build history menu

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

User needs the ability to perform particular action in Jenkins UI on any of the job builds that are already finished with access to the build`s ID.

For each build in history there is menu with items "Changes", "Console output", "Delete build", "Rebuild" etc. Can I add a custom command into that menu using an existing plugin? The command will be "pass build ID to a script on Jenkins machine and launch the script" or at least "put build ID to a file" or "pass build ID to another job and launch it".

Is there any plugin that can do that?

The workarounds I am currently aware of are the following:

- a separate Jenkins job that gets required build ID (needs launching another job, correct copying of the build ID)
- rename build using menu item "Edit Build Information", then a script/cron job on Jenkins machine will do what it needs to (requires correct renaming)
- putting a link to script into html report
- artifact an html with the link to script

Looked at the plugins like "batch-task", "sidebar-link" etc., but all work on job level and not on build level.

P.S. It is a free-style Jenkins job, pipeline / Groovy has not been used.
Perhaps a Groovy script might help? How can it look like and how to make launching such script user-friendly (ideally with one button)?